# gutter space in HTML web page(Responsive page issue)

Tags: html, css

I created two DIVs that I created a CSS file for, but the view on device mode whenever I switch displays an unwanted gutter space and I have not been able to fix that or know the cause of it.  I will appreciate some help on this one.
The CSS code:

```
    div.paragraph{
    padding-top: auto;
    width: 60%;
    font-family: tahoma;`enter code here`
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 100px;
    position: relative;

    }
    div.vision{
    padding: 0  0 0;
    float: right;
    width:30%;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background:     gray;
    height: auto;
    margin: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 70%;
    text-align:  center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have one div next to another?

Comment: no. the purpose of the divs is to enable me structure the page the way i want but my problem is when i toggle it in device modes the unwanted gutter is what i do not want to see. i do not know if the problem is from my css that is why i sent the code. the output looks normal on large screen and messed up on small screen.